# MySQL - Operand should contain 1 column(s),I want to know how to optimize this sql

Tags: mysql

I want to know how to optimize this sql.

This is table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `orders` (
  `id` bigint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `order_no` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `factory_id` bigint DEFAULT NULL COMMENT,
  `hotel_id` bigint DEFAULT NULL COMMENT,
  `floor_id` bigint DEFAULT NULL COMMENT,
  `order_finish_time` varchar(30) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_general_ci;

CREATE TABLE `collections` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `factory_dept_id` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
  `hotel_dept_id` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
  `hotel_fioor_id` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_general_ci;

CREATE TABLE `collection_linen_detail` (
  `id` bigint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `collection_id` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
  `type` char(1) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `count` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `create_time` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=7 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_general_ci;
```

```
select
            o.id, o.order_no, o.order_finish_time, 
            (select ifnull(sum(case when(type='1') then count else null end),0) as totalNormalCountCollections from collection_linen_detail where TO_DAYS(create_time) <= TO_DAYS(o.order_finish_time) and collection_id = co.id) totalNormalCountCollections,
            (select ifnull(sum(case when(type='3') then count else null end),0) as totalNormalCountCollections from collection_linen_detail where TO_DAYS(create_time) <= TO_DAYS(o.order_finish_time) and collection_id = co.id) totalPollutionCountCollections,
            (select ifnull(sum(case when(type='6') then count else null end),0) as totalNormalCountCollections from collection_linen_detail where TO_DAYS(create_time) <= TO_DAYS(o.order_finish_time) and collection_id = co.id) totalSceneReturnCountCollections
from orders o
left join collections co on o.factory_id = co.factory_dept_id and o.hotel_id = co.hotel_dept_id and co.hotel_fioor_id = o.floor_id
```

The following is another implementation with the following error message:Unknown column 'o.order_finish_time' in 'where clause',

```
select
            o.id, o.order_no, o.order_finish_time, 
            cld.totalNormalCountCollections,cld.totalPollutionCountCollections,cld.totalSceneReturnCountCollections
from orders o
left join collections co on o.factory_id = co.factory_dept_id and o.hotel_id = co.hotel_dept_id and co.hotel_fioor_id = o.floor_id
left join (select
               collection_id,
               ifnull(sum(case when(type='1') then count else null end),0) as totalNormalCountCollections,
               ifnull(sum(case when(type='3') then count else null end),0) as totalPollutionCountCollections,
               ifnull(sum(case when(type='6') then count else null end),0) as totalSceneReturnCountCollections
            from collection_linen_detail
            where TO_DAYS(create_time) <= TO_DAYS(o.order_finish_time)
            GROUP BY collection_id
           ) cld on cld.collection_id = co.id
```

Very much looking forward to being helped!

Comment: if you add table definitions as text then we can see what indexes you have in place and the storage engine , character sets and collations in use , If you add an explain plan we can see what the optimizer thinks and if you add sample data an expected outcome we might suggest alternate solutions..As is you have published 2 non working queries for us to reverse engineer / guess  data model..and mocking up tables and data is not something I for one am keen to spend time on.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: https://xyproblem.info/

Comment: You can't join with a correlated subquery. The relationship between the subquery and other tables is only in the `ON` condition.